# php file uploader not uploading

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

I'm making an uploader for a website which is designed to upload videos.  As of now, it doesn't check if they're videos, it's simply uploads them.  I do this through a simple form that selects a file and submits it to `upload.php`.  Here is the HTML which I do this with:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="startUpload();">
Video Name: <input type="text" name="name" class="maininput" style="width:300px;" maxlength="80"><br>
File: <input name="myfile" type="file" class="mainbutton"/ style="clear:both;"><br>
Description: <br><textarea cols="43" rows="10"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" class="mainbutton"/>
</form><br><br><br>
<p id="f1_upload_process">Loading...<br/><img src="/images/loader.gif" width="20" height="20" /></p>
<p id="result"></p>

<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.top.window.stopUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>);
</script> </iframe>
```

Here are my javascript functions which accompany this:

```
function startUpload(){
    document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'visible';
    return true;
}
function stopUpload(success){
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
       '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
           '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      return true;   
}
```

And finally, here is the contents of upload.php, which I use for actually uploading the file:

```
<?php
   $result = 0;

   $target_path = "videos/";
   $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
    }

   sleep(1);
?>
```

I believe that the issue is with the upload.php.  The problem is not with anything client side, it's the fact that in the client, it uploads the file, but I can't find the file in the videos folder, or any folder in the server directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is what I use, you can customize it to suit your script:**

**Simply change the *path and *variables.**

```
<?php
// Configuration - Your Options
$allowed_filetypes = array('.mov','.mp3','.mp4','.flv'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
$max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
$upload_path = './files/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

// Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

// Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

// Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!is_writable($upload_path))
die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

// Upload the file to your specified path.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
else
echo 'There was an error during the file upload. Please try again.'; // It failed :(.

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My next problem is a limit imposed by the .htaccess file.  Is this common?

Comment: @RyanSparks You're welcome. As for the limit imposed by an .htaccess file, it isn't common, however check what your `php.ini` file is set to and see what the upload max limit is set at.

Comment: @RyanSparks The default upload max is usually set to 10 or 20M. To check this, make up a file called `php_info.php` with this inside and run it from your browser. `<?php phpinfo();?>` It will also show you all your MAX limits and complete PHP server info.

Comment: Thanks! As a matter of fact, this was causing my error all along.  Do most hosts let you edit the php.ini file to expand that limit? If not, is there a set of hosts that do? Like, does HostGator?

Comment: @RyanSparks Was the `php.ini` file giving you the problem or the `.htaccess`? Some hosts do let you edit the `php.ini` file, while some don't. For the ones that don't, there are ways to override those in many ways; one of which being to make up your own `php.ini` file and upload it to your `cgi-bin`. Least, that's how my host works. Do a search for PHP.ini override settings, there's a lot of info out there.